# How to set Threading Mode in Elastic Search JAVA API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

As per the documentation,

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/search.html#_operation_threading_3

we can set Threading Model for Elastic search JAVA API

But which java class/method will allow us to do this ? is there any code sample for the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threading mode was removed in Search API: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9917